# Recharts - Horizontally Align Line and Bar Charts

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts, recharts

I am using Recharts and have a component that displays a line chart followed by a bar chart. The two charts are displaying the same seven day span, but the ticks are not aligned. The line chart starts on the Y Axis line, while the bar chart has left padding (by default).

On the line chart I tried adding padding={{left: 100 }}, which got the starting of the X axes aligned, but the rest of the ticks were off, and more importantly it isn't responsive to the screen size. As far as I can tell using something like '5%' is not allowed.

On the bar chart I tried setting the padding to zero and a negative number, but ran into the same issues with responsive scaling and tick misalignment.

Is there a way to align the ticks and data on the two graphs?

Here is the code:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={300} >
  <LineChart width={350} height={300} data={this.props.data.activityResponse.edges} connectNulls={true} >
    <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36}/>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="node.participation" stroke={this.participationColor} name="Participation" strokeWidth={this.strokeWidth} />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="node.focus" stroke={this.focusColor} name="Focus" strokeWidth={this.strokeWidth} />
    <XAxis dataKey="node.logDate" tickFormatter={this.formatXAxis} />
    <YAxis dataKey="node.participation" >
      <Label value="%" position="insideLeft" />
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip content={this.renderResponseTooltip} />
  </LineChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={300} >
  <BarChart width={350} height={300} data={this.props.data.activityStep.edges} connectNulls={true} >
    <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36}/>
    <Bar dataKey="node.stepCount" fill={this.stepColor} name="Steps" />
    <XAxis dataKey="node.logDate" tickFormatter={this.formatXAxis} />
    <YAxis dataKey="node.stepCount" >
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip content={this.renderStepTooltip} />
  </BarChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image: Recharts Line and Bar chart alignment]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you are still interested in this, since the question is pretty old, but I have found a solution that worked for me.

You can use `ComposedChart` to solve this. Taking your code, the solution should look something like this:

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={300} >
  <ComposedChart data={this.props.data.activityResponse.edges} connectNulls={true} >
    <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36}/>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="node.participation" stroke={this.participationColor} name="Participation" strokeWidth={this.strokeWidth} />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="node.focus" stroke={this.focusColor} name="Focus" strokeWidth={this.strokeWidth} />
    <XAxis dataKey="node.logDate" tickFormatter={this.formatXAxis} />
    <YAxis dataKey="node.participation" >
      <Label value="%" position="insideLeft" />
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip content={this.renderResponseTooltip} />
  </ComposedChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
<ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={300} >
  <ComposedChart data={this.props.data.activityStep.edges} connectNulls={true} >
    <Legend verticalAlign="top" height={36}/>
    <Bar dataKey="node.stepCount" fill={this.stepColor} name="Steps" />
    <XAxis dataKey="node.logDate" tickFormatter={this.formatXAxis} />
    <YAxis dataKey="node.stepCount" >
    </YAxis>
    <Tooltip content={this.renderStepTooltip} />
  </ComposedChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

I also removed your width / height arguments on the charts since the ResponsiveContainer will take care of that already.

In my personal case, this solves the issue, when I try to horizontally align an Area and a Bar Chart.

[image]

Providing a syncid for both charts, by adding that attribute to both ComposedCharts, the Tooltip will also follow in both charts simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Did not work for me. I also do not understand how putting two `ComposedChart` next to each other automatically aligns your axis? (`syncId` AFAIK is only for tooltips)
Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This link might help in this case.

Try `syncId="anyId"` on both LineChar and BarChar element.

[Rechart - SynchronizedLineChart](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart#syncId)